# Crystal Reports muestra error de conexión

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

He creado un aplicativo en Vb.net usando también Crystal Reports, hice el ejecutable y lo he probado en una computadora distinta a la que he usado para hacer el software. Me muestra el siguiente error, espero sugerencias para solucionar el problema, muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ojo que antes de probarlo en la computadora donde me aparece el error lo he probado en mi computadora y no hay ningún problema con el instalable en mi computadora.

Comment: Deberías colocar el código con que cargas el frmReporte (el CrystalReportsViewer) y a donde referencias el archivo .rpt para que podamos orientarte.

Comment: Agustín, aquí comparto el código contigo:
rptLUni = New rptCartas
rptLUni.SetDataSource(dtLU)
frmReporte.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptLUni
frmReporte.ShowDialog()
frmReporte.Dispose()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno encontré la solución a mi problema y lo posteo por si a alguien le sirve: Solo necesitaba instalar y configurar el [mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-win32](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

Para configurar dicho conector deben acceder y ejecutar el archivo: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe y luego hacen su conexión a Mysql (Tal cual especificaron en su Crystal Report).

A mi me funcionó perfecto. Espero le sirvan a todos.

Comment: Ricky puedo aconsejarte intentar desprenderte de lo posible del ODBC. Puedes utilizar el .DLL nativo de MySQL para .NET y transportarlo en tu proyecto sin necesidad de instalar en cada computadora el Connector.

Comment: Mmm sí lo uso, y lo hago para traer información de la base de datos a mis formularios en VB.net. El tema del ODBC lo uso para mostrar subreportes en Crystal Reports no encontré otra forma...

Comment: @Ricky ya que hallaste la solución, pPor favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave hecho!